# Ошибка кодировки Django

Tags: python, django

Сделал небольшой блог и решил выложить на сервер. При запуске выдает следующее:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file /root/django-news/article/models.py on line 13, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

**Содержимое файла models.py:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'article'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    # Метод для корректного отображения заголовков статей
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def getSmallText(self):
        if len(self.text) > 200:
            return self.text[:200]
        else:
            return self.text


class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'comment'

    text = models.TextField(default=None)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
```

На моей машине работает хорошо. Вроде кодировку utf-8 указал, что ему еще надо ?

Comment: 1- проверьте окончания строк (`b'\r\n'` vs. `b'\n'`)—часть, реализующая pep-0263 возможно может не понимать неродные окончания строк на некоторых версиях Питона 2- проверьте что исходники именно те используются, которые вы думаете (совпадают пути к `models.py`?)

Comment: Судя по тому, что кодировка файла указана, а на 13-й строке нет Юникодных символов, проблема или в другом `models.py` или в использовании скомпилированной предыдущей версии. Я бы попробовал удалить все `.pyc` файлы на сервере.